# linux issue setenv command not found

Tags: linux, setenv

I develop a Tcl/Tk script tool in Linux. In order to run the tool, every time I need to set the environment variable like this in shell:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64
```

and then use "wish" interpreter to launch my tool:

```
/abc/software/new2015/GE/tcl_tk/bin/wish mytool.tk
```

To make it a little easy to use, I want design a shell script "abc_wish" and put the above command inside:

```
#!/bin/sh
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64
wish="/abc/software/new2015/GE/tcl_tk/bin/wish"
exec $wish $@
```

And then I need just run:

```
./abc_wish mytool.tk
```

But error message shows that setenv command not found!I am totally new to such system issues, need some help about these stuffs. Hope I have shown the issue clearly.

Comment: **Why** is your `glibc` under `/opt/lsf`?

Comment: In fact, I have no idea about the meaning of this part "/opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib". As I mentioned I am totally new to system staff.So for each server, this path is same or not?

Comment: That looks like a partial (and typo(d)) linux from scratch toolchain path to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setenv` is a `csh` command, not a `sh` command. The equivalent in `bash` is `export`:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64:/abc/software/new_2015/GE/tcl_tk/lib64
exec wish "$@"
```

You should also put `$@` in quote, to ensure proper re-quoting of the expansion.

Comment: Oh,yes,thank you. I change the code, it works well now.